# How to convert data from row to column in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table that looks like this

[image]

and I want it like below, how should I do it in sql? If I use `GROUP BY` I am unable to use max, min functions on strings

result I want.
[image]

Comment: Check pivoting concept: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177410(v=sql.105).aspx

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Efficiently convert rows to columns in sql server](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15745042/efficiently-convert-rows-to-columns-in-sql-server)

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT *
FROM TableName t
 PIVOT (MAX(Name)
        FOR EMPLOYEETYPE
        IN (ENGINEER, MANAGER, TECHNICIAN)
       )p
```

Since you have mentioned, you have joins and some other stuff in your actual query all you need to do is

```
SELECT * FROM 
(
  /* 
                  Your Query here  
    just make sure it is only returning the columns shown in your question  
*/
)t
     PIVOT (MAX(Name)
            FOR EMPLOYEETYPE
            IN (ENGINEER, MANAGER, TECHNICIAN)
           )p
```

Comment: THE first table is actually a subquery which gets the data from 3 tables by joining them. Adding pivot to it is not working for me

Comment: If a project can have more than 1 person of the same type, you'll need to use row_number in the pivot. Otherwise this will only show max. one person per type per project